# apache2 - dynamic subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2

I have this configuration of virtualhost on my server. Everything works correctly except subdomain with www. When I go to URL with www I get the 404 error. I tried to solve this problem with mod rewrite but I did not know how to do it. Could someone help me? Thanks.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@localhost
    ServerName *.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/sub/%-3+
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DocumentRoot` instead of `VirtualDocumentRoot` for `www.domain.com`?

Comment: I tried `DocumentRoot` but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use wildcards on ServerName (as opposed to ServerAlias), perhaps that's causing problems somehow? Try `ServerName domain.com` on the wildcard virtual host.

Also, you should probably post the 404's in your error_log. The actual path reported missing may come handy to know how apache is resolving the request.